how to process a sequence of items in groups of N at a time
Sequentially one after another:
for i in $(ls -1) ; do command $i ; done

All at one time:
for i in $(ls -1); do \
 ( \
  command $i ; done ; \
 ) & \
done; wait

How to say only for example 4 or 8 at once?

(1) Bash pitfall number one. (2) GNU parallel.

In both of your examples, you run command with a single argument. Is your question about running command with N (more than one) arguments, or is it about running N background tasks at a time?

Also, as an aside, you don't need any of the \  characters you have there. Just move to the next line. You can break after the do and after a ( and after a & and after the done.

for i in $(ls -1) is very wrong. Just for i in *

I'm assuming OP's reference to command is a placeholder for some other binary (as opposed to calling the bash builtin named command).
Create some files:
$ touch a.txt b.txt 'c d e.pdf' g.dat i.txt k.txt 'l m n.pdf' qrst.pdf$'\r'
$ mkdir dir1
$ touch dir1/XXX.txt

$ ls -1F
a.txt
b.txt
'c d e.pdf'
dir1/
g.dat
i.txt
k.txt
'l m n.pdf'
'qrst.pdf'$'\r'

$ tree
.
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
├── c d e.pdf
├── dir1
│   └── XXX.txt
├── g.dat
├── i.txt
├── k.txt
├── l m n.pdf
└── qrst.pdf\015

A simple shell script to process filenames:
$ cat my_command
#!/bin/bash

printf "my input:%s:\n" "$@"
sleep 4

General approach:

use find to generate a list of files from the current directory
feed the files to xargs and let xargs handle running N copies of my_command at a time

One approach:
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -r -P3 -n1 my_command

Where:

find / -print0 terminates items with the null character and xargs / -0 allows delimiting by null character; allows white space, quotes and backslashes to be treated as literal characters
-P3 - run at most 3 copies of my_command at a time
-n1 - submit one filename at a time to my_command

This generates:
my input:./b.txt:           # 3 lines of output printed in quick succession
my input:./g.dat:
my input:./l m n.pdf:
                            # 4-sec delay
my input:./i.txt:           # 3 lines of output printed in quick succession
my input:./c d e.pdf:
my input:./k.txt:
                            # 4-sec delay
my input:./a.txt:           # only 2 filenames left so only 2 copies of my_current called to generate 2 lines of output in quick succession
:y input:./qrst.pdf         # notice the last ':' is displayed at the start of the line; this indicates the filename's trailing '\r' has been maintained
                            # 4-sec delay


Note that, compare to ls, find does include hidden files (and doesn't sort the list of files though here given that files are processed in parallel, the order is not deterministic anyway).

for i in seq 1 $(cat howmany.txt); do cryptsetup --key-file file$i.key --header file$i.header --batch-mode luksFormat file$ ; done
in howmany.txt is the number 20. how to use xarg -P4 to run this command 4 times at the same time?

@user447274 I'd recommend you take the answers you've received here, see if you can wrangle them into a solution for your new requirement, and if you have issues then ask a new question

If switching to zsh is an option:
autoload zargs
zargs --eof= -rl1 -P4 -- *(N) '' cmd --

Would run cmd -- file, 4 in parallel for the files in the current working directory.
The default eof delimiter is --, but we're switching to the empty string here (as a file name cannot be empty) in case there may be a file called -- in the current working directory. / would have also worked.
*(N) expands to a sorted list of all the non-hidden files in the current working directory like * but in a Nullglob fashion so that if there's no match it expands to nothing instead of reporting an error.
ls -1 outputs the same list of files, but since it outputs them newline delimited by default, there's no way to get back to the list of files as newline is as valid a character as any in a file name. Even if we assume file names don't contain newlines, you'd have to tune your $(ls -1) split(+glob) operator so it splits only on newline and (in shells other than zsh) disable the glob part.
If your cmd accepts options but does not accept -- as option delimiter, you could replace cmd -- with cmd and *(N) with ./*(N) to avoid problems with file names that start with - (as cmd would then be run as cmd ./-those-files-).
Note that it runs them in batches of 4, and doesn't start a new batch until the first one has finished. You may prefer GNU xargs -P behaviour that always tries to have up 4 jobs running in parallel:
xargs -r0 -P4 -l1 -a <(print -rNC1 -- *(N)) cmd --

That one you can also do with bash (and if your system has bash (the GNU shell), there are chances it will have GNU xargs):
print0() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\0' "$@"; }
xargs -r0 -P4 -l1 -a <(
  shopt -u failglob
  shopt -s nullglob
  print0 *) cmd --

With the parallel command from moreutils (not GNU parallel though GNU parallel will have an equivalent way to do it):
parallel -j4 cmd -- ./*(N) # zsh
(shopt -u failglob; shopt -s nullglob
 exec parallel -j4 cmd -- ./*) # bash

The -- there signifies to parallel the end of the command to run, it is not an argument passed to cmd, hence the need of the ./ prefix to guard against file names starting with - as noted above.

Another option would be to put all files in an array and then take consecutive array slices:
#!/bin/bash

## No error if a glob matches nothing
shopt -u failglob
## Return null if a glob doesn't match instead of
## returning the glob pattern itself as a string
shopt -s nullglob

## set the target directory; default to the current one if no argument given
target=${1:-.}
## store the contents of $target in the array $files
files=( "$target"/* )

## Iterate over the array in groups of 4
i=0
while [ $i -lt  ${#files[@]} ]; do
  end=$((i+4))
  subset=("${files[@]:$i:4}")
  echo "subset $i - $end: ${subset[@]}"
  ((i+=4))
done

That script will process groups of 4 (note that it will also process directories as well as files) in whatever directory you tell it to search through. If you run it with no arguments, it will iterate over the current directory. For example:
$ tree
.
├── file1
├── file10
├── file11
├── file12
├── file2
├── file3
├── file4
├── file5
├── file6
├── file7
├── file8
└── file9

1 directory, 12 files

$ foo.sh
subset 0 - 4: ./file1 ./file10 ./file11 ./file12
subset 4 - 8: ./file2 ./file3 ./file4 ./file5
subset 8 - 12: ./file6 ./file7 ./file8 ./file9


Note that there were some issues in the loop youbhad in your question. first of all, you don't want to iterate over the output of ls and certainly not using a for loop. See Bash Pitfall #1. You also don't need any of the \ you had there, as they were all placed in places where you can naturally move to the next line. Here's a better version of the same thing:
for i in *; do
 ( 
  command "$i"
 ) & 
done
wait

Or, if you don't really need the subshell, just:
for i in *; do
  command "$i" &
done
wait 

